# Create a conditional variable for Blackjack

Tags: javascript, html

I'm  new to JavaScript and I'm going through scrimba's JavaScript course. I'm on a blackjack project and I'm going off the beaten path by adding an array to pull from for all 52 cards instead of just numbers. Everything's working, except I'm unsure of where to even look for giving the Ace 2 separate choices for 11 or 1.

I thought to use a function for it and adding a button when the ace appears in you're hand

like I said I haven't actually tried anything but here are how I have the array and Array_cards setup

```
const K = 10
const Q = 10
const J = 10
const A = 11

const K = 10
const Q = 10
const J = 10
const A = 11

const array_cards = \[A, A, A, A, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8,
8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, J, J, J, J, Q, Q, Q, Q, K, K, K, K\]

const randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() \* array_cards)
let firstCard = Math.floor(Math.random() \* array_cards.length);
let secondCard = Math.floor(Math.random() \* array_cards.length);
let sum = array_cards\[firstCard\] + array_cards\[secondCard\];`
```

Comment: I apologize for any misunderstanding on my part of how to format questions or explanations of coding issues

Comment: *"I haven't actually tried anything"* - You're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue before asking, otherwise, we'd be writing the code for you, and that's not the purpose of Stackoverflow. You'll have to research on how to prompt the Player for a value when an Ace is drawn, don't hard-code the value of `A` as `11`, etc etc.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your input. I'll try better to follow T&E practices

Comment: No problem! Some advice (or the way I would approach this), is defining a "Deck" (like you have) and a Score (0). Then, in a loop (which you don't have currently), "draw" a card from the deck (you're doing this, but you're not removing the card, so it can be drawn again). If an Ace is drawn, prompt for a value 1 or 11 (unless selecting 11 would increment the score over 21, causing a "bust"). As long as the score is less than 21, prompt the player to continue drawing cards until they choose not to, or score is over 21. Voila; Blackjack (ish)!

Comment: Considering the rules of Blackjack, prompting the user for the value of an ace when he gets it isn't the way to go. Make its value 11 if doing so doesn't put the total value of the hand over 21, and make it 1 otherwise. Also, as cards are dealt, the value of an ace can change from 11 to 1 to suit the situation. (For example, the player's hand is [A, 6], which is a soft 17, and the player decides to draw another card and gets another 6. He now has [A, 6, 6], which is a hard 13.)

Comment: @RobH Is that how an Ace works in Blackjack? Been a very long time since I've last played; I'm very likely misremembering  Edit: On reading your whole comment, I see what you're saying; the value of an Ace is fluid, dependent on the other card, so yeah, hard assignment is not correct.

Comment: @Trey_Townley Yes, the ace can change value from 11 to 1 to avoid a bust as cards are drawn. (That's why combinations that have an ace that's valued as 11 are called soft.)

Comment: @RobH You `@`ed the wrong person, but cheers for the confirmation 